# ¿Cómo realizar comando itraf desde PHP y obtener su salida?

Tags: php, linux

Estoy trabajando con un router multimedia con Linux Linaro como SO. Estoy atascado cuando intento monitorizar la red del router. Me he descargado el `iptraf`, y la verdad que va genial si lo ejecuto desde el PUTTY. El problema viene cuando lo ejecuto desde PHP ese mismo comando. Os paso el comando en cuestión:

```
shell_exec("iptraf -i wlan0 -L ../../../mnt/web0/mantenimientoV2/log2.txt");
```

Con este comando lo que consigo es que cree un log en tiempo real y vaya escribiéndolo. Pues bien, como os comentaba, si lo hago desde la consola genial, me crea el log y lo va rellenando. Pero al hacerlo desde PHP  no consigo que cree si quiera el fichero, ¿qué podría estar pasando?

Comment: Buenas, probaste a hacer lo mismo pero usando `exec()` en lugar de `shell_exec()` ?

Comment: no hay manera tampoco con exec()...

Comment: podria ser que es una aplicacion de estas visuales de shell y al no estar en ella no lo haga desde php?

Answer (score 3):

La herramienta `iptraf` sólo puede ser ejecutada como usuario `root`. Si la ejecutas con un usuarios sin privilegios (`apache2` suele ejecutarse con el usuario `www-data`) recibirás el siguiente mensaje:

```
$ iptraf -i eth0

IPTraf Version 3.0.0 Copyright (c) Gerard Paul Java 1997-2004l

This program can be run only by the system administrator
```

Aunque no estés viendo nada en el navegador, estás recibiendo ese mensaje de error en el error estándar, por lo que `apache2` lo guarda en el log de error de ese host virtual.

Te recomiendo que uses `sudo` para esta tarea creando un archivo con el comando `visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/iptraf-apache` que contenga:

```
www-data ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/iptraf *
```

Y luego desde PHP uses:

```
shell_exec("sudo iptraf -i wlan0 -L ../../../mnt/web0/mantenimientoV2/log2.txt");
```