# Refrescar navegador raspberry remotamente desde otro navegador

Tags: php, linux

Tengo un equipo A y un equipo B en la misma red. El equipo B es una raspberry con raspbian con un navegador chromium mostrando un html ubicado en /var/www/html(se está lanzando un apache). Necesito refrescar el navegador del equipo B desde el equipo A mediante el navegador de este que consulta el servidor apache del equipo B, para ello lanzo un **fichero.php** ubicado en el equipo B con el siguiente código, pero no sucede nada:

```html
<?php

exec("/bin/sh /var/www/html/refrescar.sh");

?>
```

El fichero **refrescar.sh** se encarga de refrecar el navegador del equipo B y si lo ejecuto por linea de comandos en el equipo B, funciona.

El problema está en el *exec()* de php que ejecuta los comandos del equipo B mediante el usuario www-data, y creo que esto es el causante de que no funcione.
Ya he probado a darle permisos al usuario www-data en el equipo B, y todas las cosas que se me ocurrieron así que creo que la solución es no usar **exec()**

Comment: ¿ Exactamente que permisos tiene tu script `refrescar.sh` ?

Comment: ¿Qué contiene `/var/www/html/refrescar.sh`? Quizá con un `sudo` se pueda arreglar. Mira en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/7221/c%c3%b3mo-realizar-comando-itraf-desde-php-y-obtener-su-salida/27786#27786) cómo uso `sudo` para ejecutar una instrucción con los permisos de otro usuario desde el servidor web. Habría que cambiar el `ALL=(root)` por `ALL=(usuario)` donde `usuario` sería el usuario con el que necesitas ejecutar las instrucciones y en vez de usar `sudo <...>` a secas usarías `sudo -u usuario <...>`.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes refrescar la pagina en la `Raspberry` con `JavaScript`

```js
function actualizar(){  
   location.reload(true);
   //Muestro esto en consola solo para demostrar que se ejecuta la recarga
   console.log('recargando');  
}
//Función para actualizar cada 4 segundos(4000 milisegundos)
setInterval("actualizar()",4000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Soy una pagina autorecargable!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```